# Nandikeshvara Purana

Tags: puranas, nandi, nandikeshvara

Does any one know of a copy of Sri Nandikeshvara Purana (also known as Brhan-Nandikeshvara Purana) available any where?

Online or printed copy is fine, though I prefer printed ones. I need the text in Sanskrit as opposed to abridged / translated narrations. Translation is fine, and will be helpful, but not without the original Sanskrit slokhas (please take the qualifier "original" in context).

Grateful for any pointers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I found the text online [Nandi-Purana](https://www.vyasaonline.com/nandi-purana/) from [Vysaonline site](https://www.vyasaonline.com/)

I thought of adding this to the question instead of answering this way, but then the question won't make sense any longer.

I thought of deleting this, but then felt this might be a useful entry for someone else who may be interested in the future.

Hence decided to post this as an answer. If others know of different sources, please continue to post your answers.